# Can't insert a row in database

Tags: insert

I've got a little problem.

My php script won't insert a row in the database.

Here is my script:

```
INSERT INTO Keys (Key, Id1, Id2, Id3, Id4, Id5) 
VALUES ('kjlkjl', 986, 87, 7, 8, 5)
```

[Hastebin script](https://hastebin.com/okonoxovid.xml)

I always get the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Keys (Key, Id1, Id2, Id3, Id4, Id5) VALUES ('kjlkjl', 986, 87, 7, 8, 5)' at line 1

Is there a way that I can fix this? I've tried all the possibilities to do it (MySQLi Object-oriented, MySQLi Procedural and PDO)

Thanks for your time,
Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are using a reserved keyword for mySQL (**key** : the name of first column), try to change it to another keyword ('identifiant' for example), remember that there's some keywords reserved for mySQL like **table**, **column**, **row**, avoid using them as names.

Comment: wait, what do i have to change? I don't really understand, I'm sorry

Comment: change the name of colum Key, and the name of the table Keys to something else ...